# Multiply Column of One Dataframe by a Value from Another Dataframe, Determined by a Key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to take a large dataframe with around 26,000 rows, foodList, and multiply the column foodList['food_quant'] by a certain value from the dataframe foodConversions. To determine this value from foodConversions, another column foodList['food_name'] has a string which corresponds to the index of foodConversions. I am doing this to convert grams of different foods to calories, and each food type has a different number of calories.

I've tried doing nested loops to go through every value in foodConversions and see if it is equal to foodList['food_name'], but that's super slow and never actually finishes running for some reason; hence, I would prefer to move away from this method.
I have also tried using applymap and a lambda function, but I don't think I've done this right.
Lastly, I've tried to use the methods outlined in another stackoverflow problem, but I wasn't sure how to apply it to my situation or if it even works for my situation. Here's the link to it: [Multiply dataframe with values from other dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801885/multiply-dataframe-with-values-from-other-dataframe)

Here are the two dataframes:

```py
foodConversions = pd.Dataframe([2,3], index=['meat','vegetables'], columns=['cal/gram'])
```

```
            cal/gram
meat        2
vegetables  3
```

```py
foodList = pd.Dataframe([['meat',40]['meat',30]['vegetables',20]['meat',10]], columns=['food_name','food_quant'])
```

```
    food_name    food_quant
0   meat         40
1   meat         30
2   vegetables   20
3   meat         10
```

And the output should look like:

```
    food_name    food_quant
0   meat         80
1   meat         60
2   vegetables   60
3   meat         20
```

Hopefully that made sense, I tried to be as thorough as possible so I'm sorry for the lengthy explanation. Thanks everyone for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `reindex`  or `loc` or `map` or [`merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

`reindex|loc`

```
df2.assign(food_quant=df2.food_quant*(df1['cal/gram'].reindex(df2.food_name).values))# change reindex to loc
Out[121]: 
    food_name  food_quant
0        meat          80
1        meat          60
2  vegetables          60
3        meat          20
```

`map|replace`

```
df2.assign(food_quant=df2.food_quant*df2.food_name.map(df1['cal/gram']))
df2.assign(food_quant=df2.food_quant*df2.food_name.replace(df1['cal/gram']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
print(foodList.set_index('food_name').mul(foodConversions.reindex(foodList['food_name'])['cal/gram'], axis=0).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
    food_name  food_quant
0        meat          80
1        meat          60
2  vegetables          60
3        meat          20
```